# throw exception when string is not encoded in UTF-8

Tags: java, xml

I've got method where one of input attributes is String xml. I just want to create control for encoding of that xml. If any character is in other encoding that UTF-8, error will be thrown.

can you please tell me the easiest way how to create and test it?

I've used something like this:

```
String xml = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("c:/encoding.xml")); 
Document doc = builder.parse(IOUtils.toInputStream(xml, "UTF-8"));
```

added letters like Ľ,Š,Ť,Ž,ľ,š,ť,ž and save it as cp1250 file.

but no error.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the resultant file was valid UTF-8?

Comment: How are you adding and saving?

Comment: "if any character is in other encoding than UTF-8" is not correct. `e` is a valid character in most other encodings beside UTF-8, and it's even encoded the same.

Comment: Is the content of `doc` correct or corrupt?

Comment: Note that `String` and `char` do *not* have any encoding (they use an internal representation but that is transparent to you). The things that have encodings are byte representations of `String` and `char`, such as files or byte arrays.

Comment: I'm adding letters thru notepad++, then change encoding (cp1250), save.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done natively in Java. A file is just a string of bytes, they can be interpreted however you feel like, Java by default has no way to add meaning. I recommend using this library (no I didn't write it):

http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/

Follow these instructions (copy pasted from that link):

## How to use it

1. Construct an instance of `org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector`.
2. Feed some data (typically several thousands bytes) to the detector by calling `UniversalDetector.handleData()`.
3. Notify the detector of the end of data by calling `UniversalDetector.dataEnd()`.
4. Get the detected encoding name by calling `UniversalDetector.getDetectedCharset()`.
5. Don't forget to call `UniversalDetector.reset()` before you reuse the detector instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
String xml = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("c:/encoding.xml"));
```

If this `IOUtils` is `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` then its [Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream%29) says

"Get the contents of an InputStream as a String using the **default character encoding** of the platform."

As you are saving as cp1250, I guess cp1250 is also your platform character encoding. What your code would be doing is

1. Read the file as a byte stream
2. Convert the byte stream to chars using cp1250 (platform encoding)
3. Transform the chars to Java internal representation (UTF-16)
4. Convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8
5. Create XML document

That will always work as cp1250 *really* is your file encoding, UTF-16 has every character in cp1250 and UTF-8 has every character in UTF-16.

If you want to read the bytes as UTF-8 and avoid automatic conversions, you should use one of the two-parameter variant of `IOUtils.toString()`:

```
public static String toString(InputStream input, Charset encoding)

public static String toString(InputStream input, String encoding)
```

So I would try:

```
// Helper import: I always forget if the constant is "UTF8" or "UTF-8"
import org.apache.commons.lang.CharEncoding;

String xml = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("c:/encoding.xml"), CharEncoding.UTF_8); 
Document doc = builder.parse(IOUtils.toInputStream(xml, CharEncoding.UTF_8));
```

The rule of thumb here is: **NEVER** do any byte-to-string / string-to-byte conversion without specifying the source / destination encoding.

A minor rule of thumb would be: Unless you *need* to use some other encoding, use UTF-8 everywhere.

Both of those rules of thumb are independent of your programming language of choice.