# Text File writing in Java

Tags: java

I am writing String content to text file in Java code but after writing saving file onto disk, I am getting Incorrect encoding exception, Please suggest me correct Java Code?

```
String content =fileContent;//fileContent.toString();
System.out.println("File Contt===>"+content);

File fileWrite = new File("/homeDesktop/NormalFile/"+filename);

// if file doesnt exists, then create it
if (!fileWrite.exists()) {
    fileWrite.createNewFile();
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileWrite.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(fileContent);
bw.close();
```

Comment: Could you provide the incorrect code so that we can help you fix it?

Comment: Which encoding do you use? Please provide an example of input data too.

Comment: What does fileContent contain? can you paste the error trace?

Answer (score 0):

IOUtils.toString(String) Converts your coding.
[String not encoded in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585897/throw-exception-when-string-is-not-encoded-in-utf-8)

NOTE:
You dont need this:

```
// if file doesnt exists, then create it
if (!fileWrite.exists()) {
fileWrite.createNewFile();
}
```

File create automatically a new file, if there isn't one.